# Google Analytics Track Folders Outside of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Hi I have a wordpress site which I am tracking with Google Analytics. (put GA code in the header.php) at `www.example.com`
Some of my links I have setup to redirect to `www.example.com/resources/...`

I can't see any results on GA for content in this folder
How do I get the site to track the `resources` folder (which I assume is outside of the wordpress install) so I do not have to setup to separate GA site instances.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the Google analytics tracking works is that any file containing analytics.js sends a hit to Google analytics.

What ever files you want tracked must contain the tracking snippet including any files in your `www.example.com/resources/...` directory.   Any URLs hit that do not contain the tracking snippet will not be tracked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand your point. I want to know if I have  www.example.com with the GA snippet (header.php or index.php), will this track files in the subdirectory www.example.com/resources or do I have to make a separate "Property/App" in Google Analytics to track this separate instance? Ideally I would like to see the user journey from one instance e.g Wordpress Homepage > Page > redirect link > page inside of /resources

Comment: Any files within www.example.com/resources  must also contain the snippet.   you cant just put it in the directory.  It has to be in the html file when it is served to the user.

Comment: Ah ok thx. So I put exactly the same google tracking code snippet from www.example.com/index.html in  www.example.com/resources/folder1/index.html & www.example.com/resources/folder2/index.html and so on...and this will track the the whole user journey from anywhere I have the exactly the same tracking code? Cheers

Comment: it should yes this might help as well https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en